# Crontab not recognising command

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I have a bash script which I want to run as a cron job.
It works fine except one command.
I redirected its stderr to get the error and found out that the error it shows was the command not recognized.
It is a root crontab.
Both the current user and root execute the command successfully when I type it in the terminal.
Even the script executes the command when I run it through the terminal.

**Startup script :**

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo macchanger -r enp2s0 > /dev/null
sudo /home/deadpool/.logkeys/logger.sh > /dev/null
```

**logger.sh :**

```
#!/bin/bash
dat="$(date)"
echo " " >> /home/deadpool/.logkeys/globallog.log 
echo $dat >> /home/deadpool/.logkeys/globallog.log
echo " " >> /home/deadpool/.logkeys/globallog.log
cat /home/deadpool/.logkeys/logfile.log >> /home/deadpool/.logkeys/globallog.log
cat /dev/null > /home/deadpool/.logkeys/logfile.log
cat /dev/null > /home/deadpool/.logkeys/error.log
logkeys --start --output /home/deadpool/.logkeys/logfile.log 2> /home/deadpool/.logkeys/error.log
```

**error.log**

```
/home/deadpool/.logkeys/logger.sh: line 10: logkeys: command not found
```

Comment: I can only see 9 lines in logger.sh

Comment: There is an extra blank line after '#!/bin/bash' @doctorlove

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember `cron` runs with a different environment then your user account or `root` does and might not include the path to `logkeys` in its `PATH`. You should try the absolute path for `logkeys` (find it with `which logkeys` from your user) in your script. Additionally I recommend looking at [this answer on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/85893/running-a-cron-job-manually-and-immediately?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) about running scripts like they are running from `cron` when you need to find out why it's working for you and not in a job.

Comment: It worked! Thanks for the links to the serverfault answer. @BrandonMiller